# How to Push and Replace Value in Array by Object Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm wondering if it's possible to push an object to an array and if the id `data-seats` already exists replace/overwrite the value on next click.

**Code:**

```
var active_filters = [];
$("a").on('click', function() {
    active_filters.push({id: "data-seats", value: increment_value });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible! What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I have the above with getting the object pushed to the array :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585309/replacing-objects-in-array)

Comment: But getting that to work wasn't your problem, right?

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961994/how-to-find-object-in-array-of-object-by-object-property (and the several others like it).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to push an object to an array and if the id data-seats already exists replace/overwrite the value on next click.

Yes (see below), but if you're looking for a structure for storing things by a unique key, an array isn't really your best option. An object (created with [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) so it doesn't inherit any properties) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would be a better choice. Then you'd just do

```
// With an object
active_filters["data-seats"] = (active_filters["data-seats"] || 0) + 1;
```

or

```
// With a Map
active_filters.set("data-seats", (active_filters.get("data-seats") || 0) + 1);
```

Those work because if `data-seats` isn't on the `active_filters` object/Map, `active_filters["data-seats"]`/`active_filters.get("data-seats")` is `undefined`, and `undefined || 0` is `0`. (Then we add 1 to it, and set the new value.)

But you can do it with an array: Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to see if the object already exists and then update it if it does, or add it if it doesn't:

```
var obj = active_filters.find(function(entry) { return entry.id === "data-seats"; });
if (obj) {
    ++obj.value;
} else {
   active_filters.push({id: "data-seats", value: 1});
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much TJ, this is perfect! Quick question...If using the method where I'm first checking if the object exists using find...if the value ever == 0, how can I then remove this object data-seats from array?

Comment: @Michael: For that, you wouldn't use `find`, you'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then `splice` with the resulting index.